# How to pass a variable to a JS widget in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, widget

This is my script from my phtml file:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Namespace/js/custom": {
                "ajaxShipmentUrl": "<?php echo $block->getUrl('vendor_namespace/ajax/scanShipment'); ?>"
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to get the value of my `ajaxShipmentUrl` paramater in the `custom` js file. 
This is the content of the `custom` js file:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $.widget('mage.fulfillment', {
            options: {
                // Define variables
            },
            _init: function (config) {
                console.log(config);
                // ... the rest of the script
            },
     // ... the rest of the script

     return $.mage.fulfillment;
});
```

Is there a way to get the `ajaxShipmentUrl`  in my `_init` method  ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the values passed from phtml to widget in any function using below code,

> this.options.ajaxShipmentUrl

Comment: Woaw, so fast, thnx , it works. I learnt smth today :)

Comment: Cheers bro ....